# Regarding mindfulness during practice

Tags: theravada

On personal  practice now no likes or dislike on thoughts  no thinking too. what is the stage of mindfulness?

Answer (score 1):

This stage is basic but proper mindfulness, which is to be constantly maintained. The suttas say:

> ...that bhikkhu is considered one who lives constantly
>   contemplating... strives to burn up defile­ments, comprehends readily
>   and **is mindful in order to abandon all liking and disliking toward
>   the world**.
>
> [Anapanasati Sutta](http://dhammatalks.net/Books3/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Anapanasati_Mindfulness_with_Breathing.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This stage is vicikicchā with uddhacca (doubt and indecision), it is not mindfulness.

Most of buddhist meditations can practiced by thinking of meditation's clear object. Except the eighth jhāna, nevasaññānāsaññāyatana-jhāna, because this jhāna has the strongest mind's power to focus on unclear object. **But just object is unclear, the thinking of practitioner still clearly appear.**

To resolve this problem, doubt and indecision, you must decide "I forgot my meditation object", then move your focus on meditation object, again. **For the example, if you meditating ānāpānassati, go back to focus your breath.**

Comment: To come to the question raised: So sati means remember, keep in mind and naturally involves thinking, even "like" and "dislike", e.g. judgement? It that right and propably good to add?